# rails association - has_many vs has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-associations

I am having trouble with what I thought would be a basic association.

I have a Game model and a Matchset model.

In the Game model is a list of games. The games are only listed once on the games table but they can belong to many Matchsets.

matchset.rb -

```
has_many :games
```

for game.rb I'm not sure what I would put. I don't want to put belongs_to because it belongs to many matchsets, not just one. And I don't think I would want to put has_and_belongs_to_many because matchsets shouldn't necessarily "belong to" games, but maybe I'm just looking at it wrong.

Example: Matchset 1 has games 1, 3, and 5. Matchset 2 has games 2 and 3. Matchset 3 has games 3, 4, and 5.

My background in with Oracle SQL and in my head the Matchset table would look something like this.

```
id | game_id 
1  | 1
1  | 3
1  | 5
2  | 2
2  | 3
3  | 3
3  | 4
3  | 5
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These relations should work for you:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :game_match_set_relations
  has_many :match_sets, through: :game_match_set_relations

class MatchSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :game_match_set_relations
  has_many :games,  through: :game_match_set_relations

class GameMatchSetRelation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :match_set

  validates :game_id, presence: true
  validates :match_set_id, presence: true
```

Comment: I think the join model is unnecessary

Comment: I think it is, @mechanicalfish : the OP said `The games [...] but they can belong to many Matchsets.`

Comment: Yes, so `has_and_belongs_to_many` without the model. The join table itself is of course needed.

Comment: It is recomended to use a join model in all cases, it gives you a more flexible relation, you can add extra columns on the join model, better SQL queries, more precise validations, etc etc. (see the Rails Style Guide to get all the advantages)

Comment: Good reasoning, upvoting your answer. And thanks for the link, I didn't know something like that existed.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. So I need to create the GameMatchsetRelations table to join the two. Is there something special I need to do for creating a join table like this or is it like any other table?

Comment: It is like any other table, except that I strongly recommend you to add the validations in the join model ;-)

Comment: Do I need a controller for the new table? Usually I create scaffolds and the controller is created with it but not if I create just a table. Sorry for all the questions and thanks for answering.

Comment: Or I guess what I'm getting at is how can assign game IDs to matchsets now on a matchsets form?

Comment: Yes you could use this controller to contain the logic about the relations between the matchets and the games